# Opening a drafted mail in Shared Mailbox

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have a sub that drafts an e-mail and moves that e-mail to the shared inbox. However, when i attempt to .Display the drafted e-mail it doesn't open the actual e-mail. Instead it opens/creates a new copy of the mail which ends up in my own Drafts. Any idea how I can open the drafted e-mail in the shared inbox in order to edit/send it? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim myMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim mySharedFolder AS Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim mySharedInbox As Outlook.Folder
Dim myAccount As Outlook.Account
Dim myNamespace As Outlook.Namespace

Set sBody = "insert text"

Set myNamespace = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myMailbox = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("mymail@mail.com")
Set SharedInbox = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myMailbox, olFolderDrafts)
Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myMail  = outlookApp.CreateItem("olMailItem")

With myMail
    .HTMLBody = sBody
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "mymail@mail.com"
    myMail.Move SharedInbox
    myMail.Display
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MailItem.Move` is not a sub, it is a function that returns the new item:

```
set myMail = myMail.Move(SharedInbox)
myMail.Display
```